# regexp for catch specific content in nested html tags

Tags: html, regex, tags, expression

In this example:

```
<TR valign=top>
    <TD width=2>Region</TD>
    <TD width=3>number</TD>
</TR>
<TR valign=top>
    <TD width=2>camp</TD>
    <TD width=3>33210</TD>
</TR>
```

Need a regular expression to find "region" word and catch the corresponding `<TR>...Region...</TR>` 
something like this: `<tr [^ <tr]*(region)[^ <tr]*</tr>`

Comment: HTML doesn't have a regex implementation. Are you using JavaScript, perhaps? Or a server-side script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: i do use it in Qt C++ language

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try:

```
<tr(?:(?!</tr>).)+(?:<td[^>]*>Region</td>)(?:(?!</tr>).)*</tr>
```

Basically:

- look for `<tr`
- `(?!</tr>` followed by anything that's not the closing  tag `(?!` is a negative lookahead which asserts that the following text is not present
- `.` match one character
- `+` repeat lookahead and match
- `<td[^>]*>Region</td>` match the line with 'region'
- `(?!</tr>).` - same as step 2 - this time optional (`*`)
- `</tr>` - match the closing tag